# Filter Data before it is loaded in the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on displaying some data in a GridView and am using ObjectDataSource. My code looks something like this

.aspx :

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true">
               <asp:ListItem  Text="Employee" Value="Name"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="Department" Value="Department"></asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
             <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="Button2_Click" />

   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AllowPaging="true"  PageSize="30" EmptyDataText="No data available" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee" HeaderText="Employee" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="" >
                <ItemStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
         </Columns>

  </asp:GridView>

         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" TypeName="Employees" SelectMethod="EmployeesData" />
```

I'm filtering the Data in the GridView with a dropdownlist and a search box.

aspx.cs :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState.Add("test", true);

    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Employee")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Employee LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Department")
    {

        ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Department LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' ";

    }
 }
```

And I'm loading my data from the database like this
.cs :

```
public static class Employees
{
    public static DataTable EmployeesData()
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db.vw_EmployeesConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Employee, Department FROM vw__Employees WHERE ....", conn))
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(data);
            return data;

        }

    }
}
```

Now this is all fine. However, I now had the client coming to me saying before any of the Data is displayed they want to filter it by Department(could have thought of that earlier..). So basically they want a filter function with a dropdownlist like I've already implemented BEFORE any of the data is actually loaded into the GridView and then only load the data relevant to the specific Department. Anybody got a suggestion on how to do this most efficently without re-writing most of my code?

Comment: So you want to have a department pre-selected in the dropdown when the page loads?

Comment: No there would be a dropdown list with the different departments and then the user would select one of those departments and the relevant data would be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a second `DropDownList` that you fill with the Departments from your Database when the Page is loaded. On the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of that `DropDownList` you set the visibility of your current controls to `true` and change your SQL-Queries accordingly to select only those employees that are in the selected department.

Answer (score 0):

I little bit miss what you would like to avoid, but let me then propose some solutions from my previous project:

1) How to avoid modifying server logic - the short answer place this to database layer. So use some table-function (or stored-procedure) and select from it instead of specifying `SELECT` in code

2) Please see Microsoft example to handle OnFilter event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.filterexpression(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have a drop down list and a search box, there is a solution defined in the below URL using Javascript which is very faster and filtering will be done quickly.

Please refer http://www.codescratcher.com/javascript/search-gridview-using-javascript/ . I hope it might get you the desired solution.